# How to scroll photo galley photos like folderview (eg in Flipboard app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iphone developing.Can any body tell me that how can i scroll galley photos one by one image like a folding view.

By folding view I mean the folding should work something like that for Flipboard app. In contrast to what Flipboard does, the view changes by flipping the screen view from bottom to top (or visa versa), I want to create the similar screen view change but happening for right to left (or visa versa), where the image (in gallery) folds from the centre to show the next image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea that you are searching for is ethically known as [cover flow](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html).Do have a look at the code in the link.Hope that suffices your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really easy to do this thing. But there is a really good Library at **[gitHub](https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS)**  .

If you are **new** to iOS Development stick first to the Apple Documentation and try to rebuild the native Gallery View from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this project to your needs .

[Leaves](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/leaves)

It shows the complete implementation of a folding view.